# draw free hand path on bitmap and create new bitmap from drawing part of bitmap : ANDROID

Tags: android, android-canvas, crop, android-bitmap

in detail please refer below image,

[image]

i think image clearly describe my problem that i want crop part as selected area not area inside it!

currently i am using canvas for draw free hand path and storing all **Points** on which user touches and than get crop image like,

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultingImage);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    Path path = new Path();
    for (int i = 0; i < SomeView.points.size(); i++)
    {
        path.lineTo(SomeView.points.get(i).x, SomeView.points.get(i).y);

    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);


    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC));

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);
```

so here resultingImage bitmap is my final cropped bitmap.

how can i achieve my above problem's solution.